# How to logout the current user without notices and warnings?

Tags: wp-admin, user-access, logout

I'm trying to avoid that subscriber users had access to admin. I'm using the following code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'lr_no_admin_u_access', 100 );
function lr_no_admin_u_access() {
  global $current_user;
  $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
  $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
  $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : site_url();

  if($user_role !== 'editor' && $user_role !== 'administrator'){
    wp_logout();
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect);
    exit;
  }
}
```

When a user navigates to '/wp-admin', should be logged out and redirected to the home page. Instead, a white page full of notices and warnings appears. Examples of errors:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1911

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/[site]/public_html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:1911) in /home/[site]/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6270
```

... And many more. and many more. Why? How to avoid?

Comment: Where is the code located? Have you tried asking how to log out users who aren't editors/administrators instead? Your warning is likely because you're both logging out _and_ redirecting, either of which will send headers and both require that headers have not been sent

Comment: I'm using test users (created by me). What I want is exactly to logout users that aren't editors or admin IF they navigate to wp-admin, and then redirect them directly to the website home page.

Comment: I tested only the logout (commented out wp_safe_redirect). Same issues.